# Exiting a php cron job with continue

Tags: php, cron

I'm learning PHP and have seen the following in the middle of a 160 line cron job:

```
$res2 = curl_exec($handle);
if(!$res2) continue;
```

At this point the cron job stops, so I'm guessing that "continue" is being used to exit the cron job. Is this a safe method or should exit() be called?

Comment: It's not exiting, it is just skipping the rest of the loop if the condition is met.

Comment: If it is exiting it is because skipping the rest of the loop causes it to do so.

Answer (score 4):

See the [documentation of PHP on how `continue` works](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php). Rather than stopping the script, it will only skip the remainder of a loop iteration.

If you use `continue` during the last iteration and no more instructions follow the loop, your process will terminate.

Comment: I have read the docs, and it's exiting the cron job. Hence my question because I can't make sense of it.